# modifying regexp pattern to grab more links

Tags: php

i'm doing html parse on a webpage.
i'm using regexp. 
and i'm using this pattern **" `#(['\"])(http://.*?)\\1#` "** to grab links start with **http**
but i want to modify it to grab links that has  **"rutube"** 
thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: What do you mean with "..that has "rutube".."

Comment: i want to modify the pattern #(['\"])(http://.*?)\\1# to find the word rutube

Comment: http://bit.ly/1lGtOKb sample snippet

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for that string with positive lookahead:

```
#(['"])(http://(?=.*rutube).*?)\1#
```

Comment: is it defference if the link within <iframe > tag?

Comment: @user3149609 would you clarify your mean?

Comment: the links i want to grap are within <iframe src="link"> tag is this make any defference than the the <a href >tag

Comment: @user3149609 No. it doesn't have any differences!